# Access current task PID in IBM Rhapsody 9.0.1

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I am using IBM Rhapsody 9.0.1
Following this [link](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000060dEENCA2/any-former-sdl-developers-using-rhapsody-out-there?language=it) I am trying to obtain the current task's handle, or even the OS Pid, of the current process/thread. (we are migrating from an SDL tool called TAU to Rhapsody)

Unfortunately am not able to call/reference the function `[getOsHandle()]`[2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rhapsody/9.0.1?topic=class-getoshandle) of the OXF. My class is active hence, I can see the import of `<oxf\omthread.h>` in the generated code but i cannot call the function or even use the type `RiCOSHandle`

How can I add the [OSAL classes](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rhapsody/9.0.1?topic=references-osal-classes) to my package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(int)(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(this->getOsHandle())))
```

Comment: You use a bizarre combination of C-style cast and the C++ `reinterpret_cast` in your code.

Comment: Yeah, thanks IBM for that...

Answer (score 0):

I have used

```
// Setting of the Priority of this thread.
Rhp_int32_t rv = 0; 
pid_t tid;
tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
rv = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, tid, TPRIORITY_NORMAL-20); // linux function
```